# locktime in getrawtransaction method in bitcoin-cli

Tags: bitcoin-cli, getrawtransaction

what is different between Time, BlockTime and Locktime in " Getrawtransaction " method in bitcoin CLI? Actually I want to know that is locktime. Please help me :)